# How to delete all files except large list from database?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash, find

I've a large list of files stored in the filesystem, some of them are mp4, jpgs and pdf

I want to erase all files except some of them extracted from a mysql query. e.g RandomMovie_04.mp4, AwesomeImage.jpg

This is my file structure

```
files/
    messages/
        images/
            45/ --> this is the ID in the DB
            46/
    articles/
        images/
            124/
            125/
        videos/
            124/
            207/
```

The files that **I don't want to remove** are extracted from the database

I'm using PHP (CakePHP) and MySQL

Tried this and it worked for one file, but I don't find a way for doing this with a list of files

```
find * -maxdepth 5 -not -name "RandomMovie_04.mp4" -type f -exec ls "{}" \; > list.txt
```

and this worked for two

```
find * -maxdepth 5 -not -name "RandomMovie_04.mp4" -not -name "AwesomeImage.jpg" -type f -exec ls "{}" \; > list.txt
```

I have to do this for all excluded files (in a php script)? like -not -name fileA -not -name fileB -not -name to_the_infinite...

Thanks

Sorry if my english sucks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get an array of names from your PHP script, you could create the string for `find` like this:

```
<?php 
$files = array("RandomMovie_04.mp4", "AwesomeImage.jpg", "GreatDoc.pdf");
echo implode(' -or ', array_map(function($x) { return "-name '$x'"; }, $files));
```

Which outputs:

```
-name 'RandomMovie_04.mp4' -or -name 'AwesomeImage.jpg' -or -name 'GreatDoc.pdf'
```

Your `find` command could then be:

```
find /path/to/dir -not \(  $(php files.php) \) -delete
```

And `find` will delete all the files whose names were not found.

Note that you should run this from a separate directory, otherwise the PHP file will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom :), finally I did this:
`$fullCmd = "find ".WWW_ROOT."files/  -maxdepth 4 -not ".$cmd." -type f -delete"; shell_exec($fullCmd);` where $cmd is a concatenated string (implode)

Comment: @mallendeo Consider accepting this answer or posting your own and accepting that.